# How to write javascript function to clone the row in table?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table inside div tag like this :

```
<div id="listDiv" class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="widget-box">
                    <div class="widget-content nopadding">
                        <table id="myDataTable" class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>CLCode</th>
                                    <th>QSerial</th>
                                    <th>QGroup</th>
                                    <th>Question</th>
                                    <th>Description</th>
                                    <th>AnswerType</th>
                                    <th>ManualEntry</th>
                                    <th>ScriptName</th>
                                    <th>ParameterString</th>
                                    <th>ValidFrom</th>
                                    <th>ValidTill</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="listBody">
                                @foreach (var item in Model)
                                {
                                    <tr id="@item.RowId" onchange="addRowHandlers(@item.RowId)">
                                        <td id="clCode-@item.RowId">@item.CLCode</td>
                                        <td id="qSerial-@item.RowId">@item.QSerial</td>
                                        <td><input style="max-width:100px;" type="text" id="txtGroup-@item.RowId" placeholder="QGroup" required="required" value="@item.QGroup" /></td>
                                        <td><input style="max-width:100px;" type="text" id="txtQuestion-@item.RowId" placeholder="Question" required="required" value="@item.Question" /></td>
                                        <td><textarea style="max-width:110px;" type="text" id="txtDescription-@item.RowId" placeholder="Description" required="required">@item.Description</textarea></td>
                                        @* <td>@item.SelectedAnswerType</td>*@
                                        <td>
                                            @*Answer*@

                                            @Html.DropDownList("AnswerType", new SelectList(ViewBag.AnswerTypes, @item.AnswerType), "Select Any", new { id = "answerType-" + @item.RowId + "", style = "max-width:100px;" })

                                        </td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" id="manualEntryChkBox-@item.RowId" checked="@item.ManualEntry" /></td>
                                        <td><textarea style="max-width:110px;" type="text" id="txtScriptName-@item.RowId" placeholder="ScriptName">@item.ScriptName</textarea></td>
                                        <td><textarea style="max-width:110px;" type="text" id="txtParameterString-@item.RowId" placeholder="ScriptName">@item.ParameterString</textarea></td>
                                        <td><input style="max-width:140px;" type="date" id="validFrom-@item.RowId" value=@item.ValidFromString /></td>
                                        <td><input style="max-width:140px;" type="date" id="validTill-@item.RowId" value=@item.ValidTillString /></td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit","EditRow",new {id=item.CLCode }) |
                                            @Html.ActionLink("Delete","DeleteRow",new {id=item.CLCode })                                           
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and then there is button in different tag :

@*button for adding new questionnaire*@

```
            <div style="float:left;margin-left:28px;">
                <input type="button" id="buttonForNewRow" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="addNewRowForQuestionnaire()" value="Add New Questionnaire" />
            </div>
```

This button is supposed to clone the previous row with empty textboxes and dropdown list on click.

jQuery function which i wrote was

```
function addNewRowForQuestionnaire()
    {
        //var clCode = document.getElementById('clCode').value;
        var $tr = $(this).find('#listDiv').find('#myDataTable').find('#listBody').closest('TR');

        var $clone=$tr.clone();
        $clone.find(':text').val('');
        $tr.after($clone);
    }
```

Somehow this function is not getting hit.

I have no idea why or is the function correct or not.

UPDATED, I created a method in different appraoch but then this is not working. and there are no errors also.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 1;
    function addNewRowForSameCLCode() {

        $('#buttonForNewRow').click(function () {
            $('#myDataTable tr:last').insertAfter(
                $('<tr id="newRowID' + counter + '"><td>' +
                    '<input style="max-width:50px;" type="text" id="txtQserial' + counter + '" value="" required="required" placeholder="QSerial"/>' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td>' +
                    '<input style="max-width:100px;" type="text" id="txtGroup' + counter + '" value="" required="required" placeholder="QGroup"/>' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td>' +
                    '<textarea style="max-width:110px;" type="text" id="txtQuestion' + counter + '" value="" required="required" placeholder="Question"></textarea>' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td>' +
                    '<textarea style="max-width:110px;" type="text" id="txtDescription' + counter + '" value="" required="required" placeholder="Description"></textarea>' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td>' +
                    '<select style="max-width:110px;" id="ddlAnswerType' + counter + '">' +
                    '<option value="S" selected>Select Any</option>' +
                    '<option value="N">Number</option>' +
                    '<option value="T">Text</option>' +
                    '<option value="C">CheckBox</option>' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td>' +
                    '<input style="max-width:50px;" type="checkbox" id="chkManualEntryChkBox' + counter + '" />' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td>' +
                    '<textarea style="max-width:110px;" type="text" placeholder="Script Name" id="txtScriptName' + counter + '" /></textarea>' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td>' +
                    '<textarea style="max-width:110px;" type="text" placeholder="Parameter String" id="txtParameterString' + counter + '" /></textarea>' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td><input style="max-width:110px;" type="date"  id="validFrom' + counter + '" /></td>' +
                    '<td><input style="max-width:110px;" type="date"  id="validTill' + counter + '" /></td>' +
                    '<td><i id="deleteRow" style="cursor: pointer;color:grey; font-size: 25px;padding: 2px; display:block" class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true" onclick="Remove(this)"></i></td>' +
                    '</tr>'));//.appendTo('#myDataTable');
            counter++;
            return false;
        });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: As I understand, you want to add a new blank row into the table when clicking the button. It's the last row, right?

Comment: Avoid using inline JS. Listen to the click event coming from `#buttonForNewRow` instead.

Comment: @Tomato32-yes i do . i wanted to add new row. And the first element and second element that is : Row Id and CLCode is not rquired to be cloned.So i am running into bump. I worte a function with different approach to append but does not function. Is it mandatory that every element that is being appended to existing HTML table be matched

Comment: @Terry- it is still not function for event listener function.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the $(this) in your addNewRowForQuestionnaire method is referring to the  element in your button HTML. This doesn’t contain any sub elements and so the “find” method that you call on it, which searches inside it for the selectors you input, doesn’t return an object for the rest of your code to use. I suggest experimenting in your browser’s console for a while with jQuery selectors to figure out how to address the right elements to do the task you want.